# WCF Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm trying to create a WCF Service using Silverlight Frontend. THe WCF Code is fairly simple however I keep getting `The modifier public is not valid for this item`. I have set everything to public, and cannot understand this error. Can someone please help.

Here is the code

```
[OperationContract]
public void SaveEmployee(int id, string firstname, string Lastname); 

public void SaveEmployee(int id, string firstname, string Lastname)
{
    Person NewPerson = new Person();
    string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks"].ToString();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connect))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSaveEmployee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter ParaID = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@ID",
            Value = id
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ParaID);

        SqlParameter ParaFirstName = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@firstname",
            Value = firstname
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ParaFirstName);

        SqlParameter ParaLastName = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Lastname",
            Value = Lastname
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ParaLastName);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are creating the [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) for your service, you can't provide the modificators for it's methods, only for whole interface.

Change your `OperationContract` to:

```
[OperationContract]
void SaveEmployee(int id, string firstname, string Lastname);
```